# Difference ~ぬ and ~ず

Tags: auxiliary-ず, negation

What is the difference between the negatives ~ぬ and ~ず, e.g.

。。。飲まず
。。。飲まぬ

Thanks

Comment: Apart from an archaic use, I found easy and clear examples that show the difference between ぬ and ず in modern Japanese usage at http://soudan1.biglobe.ne.jp/qa6390296.html.
I quote the answer from the article:
The examples are 少なから **ぬ** 影響を受ける and 少なから **ず** 影響を受ける.
少なからぬ is a 連語 (combined word?) which functions like an adjective that a noun follows after.
少なからぬ is an adverb. In the sentence 少なから **ぬ** 影響を受けた, 影響 is modified by 少なからぬ. So, 影響を「少なからぬ」受けた doesn't make sense. As for 少なからず影響を受けた, 受けた is modified by 少なからず, so 影響を「少なからず」受けた also make sense.

Comment: ^ `少なからぬ is an adverb.` -- えっ　　少なからぬ is an adjectival phrase, and 少なからず is an adverbial phrase じゃないの